# Can I sent values from collection in model through submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this table

```
<table id="Products" class="Products">
    <tr>
        <th>ProductId</th>
        <th>Productname</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>UnitPrice</th>
    </tr>
    <% for(int i=0; i < Model.NorthOrderDetails.Count; i++)
       {
           %>
            <tr>
        <td><%: Html.Label(Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductID.ToString()) %></td>
        <td><%: Html.Label(Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductName) %> </td>
        <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].Quantity) %></td>
        <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].UnitPrice) %></td>
        <td> <input type="submit" value="?" Name="qodel"  /> </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>

</table>
 <% } %>
```

And I want to sent to controller the value of ProductID in line which I press button. How I can do it?

Comment: add Name attribute to input as form will send all the value having name attribute. Alternatively you can also use hidden fields.

Comment: Using a hidden input is a better, more fool-proof approach. The problem with `input type="submit"` is that the value also determines the display for the button. `button type="submit"` is more versatile, but it's treated inconsistently in some earlier versions of IE. A hidden input works in every browser known to man from the dawn of the web and has no side effects.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, hidden field are good things. But if I want to get values from one line in this table, I need use hidden fields?

Comment: You could name your elements properly and use data attributes instead, but that would be more useful if you were posting to your controller with AJAX.

Comment: @Sippy Can I do it without ajax?

Comment: @ Im seriously. Now I need do it without js

Comment: @JenishRabadiya. I use Name attribute. How I can sent the value from line?

Answer (score 0):

So without Javascript you are limiting yourself slightly here, I think the code below should work but I'm sure someone can poke a hole in it!

```
<table id="Products" class="Products">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ProductId</th>
            <th>Productname</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>UnitPrice</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{ 
            for(int i=0; i < Model.NorthOrderDetails.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label(Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductID.ToString())
                    </td>
                    <td>    
                        @Html.Label(Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].ProductName) 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].Quantity)   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].UnitPrice)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Vi")
                    </td>

                    <td> 
                        <input type="submit" name="submitValue" 
                            value="@Model.NorthOrderDetails[i].SomeValue"/> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }            
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then make sure that your controller action accepts the `name` attribute of the input as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult YourControllerMethod(string submitValue) {
    ....
}
```

The code would look something like that in MVC3+, `<%` is from MVC2.

Comment: Ok. But how I can get value from line on which I press button

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not valid HTML. You can't put anything inside `<table>` other than `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` or `<tr>`. Tables make life hard.

Comment: I edit question. I want sent value from collection in Model, is it real?

Comment: JavaScript it is then!

Comment: This wont work because your generating vales with indexers, which means the POST method parameter would need to be `IEnumerable<T>` but indexers need to start at zero and be consecutive so binding would fail for all but the first item

Comment: Yeah we figured that out earlier haven't had chance to remove answer yet

Comment: Oh I can do it on this

Comment: Edited the answer, without JavaScript I can't think of a better way to do it. If anyone else can, please do share, I'd like to know as well.